# Vault - permission denied issue

Tags: kubernetes, permissions, vault

One of the pods is failing to connect to the vault and is getting a permission denied error.
I see the authentication is getting successful with `role_id` and `secret_id`. Vault-agent-init container showing
permission denied error.

```
  0/v1/secret/data/services/synapps/certificate
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
        * permission denied
```

Vault-log-shows :

```
2023-04-05T20:09:28.224Z [ERROR] secrets.system.system_105dca99: error occurred during enable credential: path=kubernetes/ error="path is already in use at kubernetes/"
2023-04-05T20:09:28.377Z [ERROR] secrets.system.system_105dca99: error occurred during enable credential: path=approle/ error="path is already in use at approle/"
```

Other similar posts are suggesting disabling the approle and creating a new one with a new role id and secret id.
But the vault login is giving issues.

```
Error storing token: open /.vault-token: permission denied
Authentication was successful, but the token was not persisted. The resulting
token is shown below for your records.
```

How to fix this issue? Please advise.

Comment: is it intermittent? and what version of the vault are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Vault unable to create plaintext copy of your token.

What can be reason?

Well your user (which permissions vault inheriting) seem have no permission to write at FS' root folder.

Why vault would write there?

Because it thinks its your home folder.

It seems you trying to run vault as anonymous user without home folder set.

It can be also  SELinux/AppArmor security policy, but not in your case.